# Repeat the foreign keys or use two tables related as a one-to-one

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, one-to-one

I have two tables `sessions` and `schedules`, and I want to add a new table `destinations`.

The `destinations` table can be related to both tables, but only **ONE** destination can be related to a `session` or `schedule`:

- N destinations -> ONE session
- N destinations -> ONE schedule

**Solution 1:**

Create a destination table with two foreign keys (id_session and id_schedule) and only populate one for each destination.

**Solution 2**

I create `destinations`, `schedule_destinations` and `sessions_destinations` with the following relations:

- 1 destinations -> 1 schedule_destinations (id_destination [UNIQUE], id_schedule) -> N schedules
- 1 destinations -> 1 session_destinations (id_destination [UNIQUE], id_session) -> N sessions

Thanks!

Comment: Solution 3 : update the tables session and schedule to add a FK to the destination table and enforce the one session : one destination/one schedule : one destination integrity constraint -> differents sessions/schedules can have the same destination, but a single session/schedule can only have one destination

Comment: This case is known as an inherited design in the CDM (Conceptuel Data Model). To do that, child tables must have a primary key that is also the foreign key of the destinations table.

Answer (score 0):

To make your structure consistent with your business rules (one relationship relates with session or schedule), I would create 2 tables:

- `schedule_destinations` with foreign key to `schedule`.
- `session_destination` with foreign key to `sessions`.

And **do not create** third table `destinations`.

In the solution, you will have different sets of different destinations. Hence, you will not have one destination to session and schedule at the same time. `Selects` I would do from both tables if you need both types destinations in the same result.